# How to write common stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I wrote two stored procedures in Visual Studio 2010. Both are returning the Id. So the logic is same for both stored procedures. Then how to write a common stored procedure to execute both queries?

```
// First stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetId
    (@Email VARCHAR(50))
AS
    SELECT Id 
    FROM tblUserRegistrations 
    WHERE Email = @Email

    RETURN

// Second stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetProviderId
    (@Email VARCHAR(50))
AS
    SELECT Id 
    FROM tblProviderRegistrations 
    WHERE Email = @Email

    RETURN
```

So the logic in both stored procedures is the same. Then how can I write a common stored procedure to execute both queries? I mean the table name should be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a second input variable to choose the table you want to query and use a `IF` statement inside.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetId
        (
        @Email VARCHAR(50),
        @QuerUsers INT
        )
    AS
IF @QuerUsers = 1
BEGIN
        SELECT Id FROM tblUserRegistrations WHERE Email=@Email
        RETURN
END
SELECT Id FROM tblProviderRegistrations WHERE Email=@Email
  RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you are going to send a same email for both of that SP to get the id. You can change your sql query to inner join. Which two table will join to each other using the email. You can also use aliases to put name on separate id.

[Visit this link for reference(SQL Innerjoin)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)